# "Movie" Model taking "Name" property of internal object "Actors"

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to Angular and Entity framework.
Here is the code from my AngularJS controller:

```
    $scope.add = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    alert(this.newMovie.Name);
    debugger;
    $http.post('api/Movie/', this.newMovie).then(function onSuccess(response) {
        alert("Added Successfully!!");
        debugger;
        $scope.showAddMovieForm = false;
        $scope.movies.push(response);
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).catch(function (response) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while adding movie! :(" + response.data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });

};
```

Here is how the Action method looks in my MovieController in MVC:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // _db.People.Where(na => movie.Actors.Any(a => a.PersonId == na.PersonId));
        _db.Movies.Add(movie);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, movie);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { movieId = movie.MovieId }));
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

Movie Model Class:

```
public partial class Movie
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Movie()
    {
        this.Actors = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> YearOfRelease { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public byte[] Poster { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProducerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Producer { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

When I put a debugger in the JS code I can see that Angular is passing the object in correct format.

But somehow when it reaches Action, the "Movie" model takes "Name" property value "Actors" object which is part of "Movie" itself.

[image: Debugger Screeshot:]

[image: ActionMethod, Movie Model Screenshot]

Not able to understand why "Movie" model is getting the "Name" property of "Actors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the way you are creating your Actors object in Movie object.

Actor should be JS Array of objects and your Movie object should look like below when you debug:

[image]

But, in your case Actors is just a single object. Hope it helps.

Comment: I see, I was having the same doubt. Let me try

Comment: @RohinTak Sure, don't forget to mark as answer if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, changed my select input to multiselect and now getting array of objects.
Solved this issue, other issues were waiting for me in advance though.

Comment: Great it worked. Happy to help. Sorry about changing the movie name in my answer :)